# Couldn't understand the Code while Plotting data with MatPlotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I was trying to implement Logistic Regression from scratch and I wanted to plot the data. 
I came across this piece of code that just bounces over my head :

```
pos , neg = (y==1).reshape(100,1) , (y==0).reshape(100,1)

plt.scatter(X[pos[:,0],0],X[pos[:,0],1],c="r",marker="+")

plt.scatter(X[neg[:,0],0],X[neg[:,0],1],marker="o",s=10)
```

This is what the data looks like :

[image]

I am especially confused about the first line. It would be very helpful if you could tell what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet was obviously taken from https://github.com/Benlau93/Machine-Learning-by-Andrew-Ng-in-Python/tree/master/LogisticRegression, where

```
df=pd.read_csv("ex2data1.txt",header=None)
X=df.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=df.iloc[:,-1].values
```

So `y` is a 1D array of `0` and `1` values (100 elements).

They create a 1D boolean array `(y==1)` which is then converted to 2D by `.reshape(100,1)`. Normally you would do this by `(y==1).reshape(-1,1)` or just `(y==1)[:,np.newaxis]`.
Then in the plot command, they use the first (and only) column of this 2D array for boolean indexing to first plot all positive data points (i.e. where y==1) and then all negative points.

So all in all this is a rather convoluted way of plotting pos and neg values separately. Normally you'd use:

```
pos, neg = y==1, y==0
plt.scatter(X[pos,0], X[pos,1], c="r", marker="+")
plt.scatter(X[neg,0], X[neg,1], marker="o", s=10)
```

or even more simply:

```
pos, neg = df[2]==1, df[2]==0 
plt.scatter(df.loc[pos,0], df.loc[pos,1], c="r", marker="+")
plt.scatter(df.loc[neg,0], df.loc[neg,1], marker="o", s=10)
```

to achieve exactly the same thing in a much more straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this link?

https://towardsdatascience.com/andrew-ngs-machine-learning-course-in-python-logistic-regression-c0ae25509feb

There appears to be missing info there. As compared to the revised version;

https://towardsdatascience.com/andrew-ngs-machine-learning-course-in-python-support-vector-machines-435fc34b7bf9

This appears to be the original;

https://laptrinhx.com/andrew-ng-s-machine-learning-course-in-python-regularized-logistic-regression-lasso-regression-1756449298/

Column names would make this easier to understand instead of [0,1,2]
I'm not great at numpy and try to avoid it..
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html

- both arrays are being reshaped into an array with 100 rows and 1 column
- pos is being assigned values where the 3rd matrice is equal to 1
- neg is being assigned values where the 3rd matrice is equal to 0
- plot is using pos[0] and neg[1]

#### You could use the pandas dataframe instead of the numpy array.

Personally I use pandas because I prefer the spreadsheet look and feel. It makes more sense to me, with named columns so it further adds to my understanding.

you could assign things easily,(without testing, I think this should work);

```
pos = df[df[2] == 1]
neg = df[df[2] == 0]

plt.scatter(pos[0].values,pos[1].values,c="r",marker="+")

plt.scatter(neg[0].values,neg[1].values,marker="o",s=10)
```

#### My two cents

I would go to Kaggle and go through things there. The Titanic Competition is a great starting point for Classification. I made this notebook for it, which scored fairly well apparently (without cheating).

https://www.kaggle.com/tamccullough/the-titanic-sank-hopefully-this-notebook-doesn-t

Answer (score 0):

```
pos , neg = (y==1).reshape(100,1) , (y==0).reshape(100,1)
```

I believe you are referring to this line, it just filters the entries, i.e.,
pos has 100 entries in y where y==1 and neg has 100 entries in y where y==0. the '.reshape(100,1) is making sure that the dimension mismatches and is (100,1) rather than (100,).